# Do not push logs to loki if not json format with promtail

Tags: logging, monitoring, grafana-loki, promtail

Can you help with my promtail config.
So, do not push logs to loki if format logs is not json format.
sample log push to loki:

```
{"level": "info", "msg": "product get done", "trace_id": "46949"}
```

and do not push to loki:

```
sample logs unformated
```

thanks for help